# How to navigate to a new page from a header button in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have a header in my component as shown below:

```
 static navigationOptions = {

        title: 'Accounts',
       headerRight:(   <OpenCamera showImageSlider={this.showImageSlider}  /> ),
      };
```

OpenCamera is a component that has a camera image.OpenCamera file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Image, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';


    export default class OpenCamera extends Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props);

        }

        render() {
            return(
                 <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => {this.showImageSlider()}} >
                     <Image style={{  width: 30, height: 30, marginLeft:100, marginRight:50}} source={require('../../../assets/img/camera.png')} />
                 </TouchableHighlight>


            );
        }
    }
```

So, now when i click on the camera icon I want to navigate to a new page called `ImageRecognitionScreen`.

So, I have imported in the StackNavigator as shown below:

```
const ServicesStack = createStackNavigator({

  ImageRecognitionScreen:ImageRecognitionScreen

}
```

and in my component i have added a function like

```
  showImageSlider = () => {
   this.props.navigation.navigate('ImageRecognitionScreen');
}
```

which I have passed in the header like :

```
  static navigationOptions = {

            title: 'Accounts',
           headerRight:(   <OpenCamera /> ),
          };
```

But, when I click on the icon, my project fails saying:

```
undefined is not an object(evaluation _this.props.navigation.navigate')
```

Can someone please help me.

Comment: try passing navigation={this.props.navigation} as props in your <OpenCamera  navigation={this.props.navigation}  />

Comment: @GauravRoy getting the error "undefined is not an object(evaluation '_class.props.navigation')

Comment: Could you post complete code rather than descriptions of the code. It's hard to tell what's going on here. For instance your camera component is calling `this.showImageSlider()` when it is clearly not defined in the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off of [@Gaurav Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11355303/gaurav-roy)'s comment, props aren't available in `static` methods/properties. However, navigationOptions will take a callback function that uses `navigation`:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: 'Accounts',
  headerRight: (
    <OpenCamera navigation={navigation} showImageSlider={this.showImageSlider}  />
  ),
})
```

However, rather than passing navigation into components, I would recommend this instead:

[Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html)

Comment: Thanks zaytrix and GauravRoy, with little bit of modification from your solution, it started working. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: this is how I have called OpenCamera component:  `static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
   
        title: 'Accounts',
       headerRight: (<OpenCamera navigation={navigation} showImageSlider={() => { navigation.navigate('ImageRecognitionScreen');}} />),
  });`